# Fluent validations on a recursive class

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a recursive data structure like

```
public class Node
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public List<List<Node>> Nodes = new List<List<Node>>();
}
```

I have defined a validator for Id property which I want to run for all the Node elements in the Nodes property. How can I do this? I tried something like

```
RuleForEach(r => r.Nodes).ChildRules(c => c.RuleForEach(x => x).SetValidator(new NodeValidator()));
```

But this seems to be running in to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an infinite loop because you're creating a new instance of `NodeValidator` within `NodeValidator`'s constructor.

You should instead assign `this` as the validator:

```
RuleForEach(r => r.Nodes).ChildRules(c => c.RuleForEach(x => x).SetValidator(this));
```